# Lagging when trying to create animation

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create a falling ball with some physics logic, When I launch the program the ball moves in a laggy and unexpected way.

I'm using a DispatcherTimer class to draw the ball every frame.

this is the code

```
        private void Draw(MyEllipse s)
        {
            var h = Canvas.GetTop(s.Ellipse);
            if (h >= cnvs.ActualHeight) //reachs the bottom
            {
                s.Velocity = s.Velocity * -1;
                s.YLoc = cnvs.ActualHeight - 1;

            }
            else //go down
            {
                s.YLoc = s.YLoc + s.Velocity;
                s.Velocity += PhysicsClass.Gravity;
            }
        }
```

My DispatcherTimer:

```
        private DispatcherTimer SetTimer()
        {
            var timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(16);
            timer.Start();
            return timer;
        }
```

Properties of MyElipse

```
       private Ellipse ellipse;
        public Ellipse Ellipse
        {
            get { return ellipse; }
            private set { ellipse = value; }
        }

        public double XLoc
        {
            get { return Canvas.GetLeft(Ellipse); }
            set { Canvas.SetLeft(Ellipse, value); }
        }


        public double YLoc
        {
            get { return Canvas.GetTop(Ellipse); }
            set { Canvas.SetTop(Ellipse, value); }
        }


        public double Velocity { get; set; }
```

Could it be that wpf cannot render quick enough?

Comment: You should write a custom animation. Reduce your calculations by doing one get of properties such as actualheight.

Comment: I think maybe a custom easing function could work. One of the standard ones such as exponentialease might come close enough if you just want an animation to look believable.

Comment: @Andy I tried to reduce calculations but it doesn't help which is weird, I remember doing way more complex animations and it still worked. I might try easing function but I still want to understand why this lagging happens

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed it by add to the dispatcherTimer priority like this

```
var timer = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Send);
```

Comment: Dispatchertimer is not really suitable for this sort of purpose. It's not intended for use as an animation clock. The accuracy of each tick is too approximate.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative implementation.

This is a quick and dirty proof of concept.

Mainwindow:

```
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" 
        ContentRendered="Window_ContentRendered"
        >
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewmodel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Canvas x:Name="canvas"  Height="800" Width="800">
            <Ellipse Height="20" Width="20" Fill="Blue"
                     Canvas.Left="{Binding X}"
                     Canvas.Top="{Binding Y}"
                     />
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Very hacky start of thread:

```
    private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var mvm = this.DataContext as MainWindowViewmodel;
        mvm.SpinUp();
    }
```

Viewmodel ( prism core nuget ).

```
public class MainWindowViewmodel : BindableBase
{
    private double x = 200;
    public double X
    {
        get => x;
        set => SetProperty(ref x, value, nameof(X));
    }
    private double y = 0;
    public double Y
    {
        get => y;
        set => SetProperty(ref y, value, nameof(Y));
    }
    private const double MAX_HEIGHT = 790;
    private double speed = 0;
    private double acceleration = 0.0982;
    private async void animateBall()
    {
        while(1==1)
        {
            while (y < MAX_HEIGHT)
            {
                speed += acceleration;
                Y += speed;
                await Task.Delay(20);
            }
            Y = 0;
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            speed = 0;
        }
    }
    public void SpinUp()
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            animateBall();
        }).Start();
    }
}
```

I'm using async await rather than dispatcher timer. This should give more consistent timings since tye timer used is more precise than dispatvher timer. It's also easier to read.

Note that the binding value change notification is automatically marshalled to the ui thread.

I've hard coded some stuff you'd want to calculate once like the gravity acceleration.

As I mentioned above this is pretty dirty code - but it gives reasonably smooth results. The ball kind of hangs up back at the top each repetition due to that 1 seconds await.